PDF output from QGIS with clickable layers AND a legend
I want to create a PDF with clickable (on/off) layers from a multilayered QGIS map - WITH - a legend and title.
I can create a PDF with clickable layers which work from the map project window using Export to GeoPDF - all good - but titles and pictures aren't exported.
I can create a PDF with a legend and other descriptive text etc in Print Layout and then export that to PDF - then GeoPDF - looks great but the layers aren't clickable in the PDF.
Am I missing something?
